AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
I need and would appreciate your kind advice on fixing the captioned server fault after I've been pending weeks to fix it but in vain.
I have 2 websites built on Google Cloud Computing Platform and run for 2 years until I updated and upgraded recently as follows;
Name Server registered with Cloudflare with DNS set with I.P. addresses without proxy.
Servers on GCP all active and running except bind9 not found, iptables disabled, but ufw enabled.
Server configuration:
Hestia CP 1.8.12 | Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.8.0-1015-gcp x86_64) | Apache 2.4.62 | mod_fcgid 2.3.9 | OpenSSL/3.0.2 | Nginx/1.27.1
Error Message on /var/log/apache2/error.log:
[proxy:error] [pid 245749:tid 245776] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock (localhost:8000) failed
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 245749:tid 245776] [client 185.191.126.213:0] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
Error Message on /home/kelliec/web/example.com/logs/example.com.net.error.log:
[error] 682075#682075: *6323 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream
ufw Status:
8080                ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache Full         ALLOW       Anywhere
8080 (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Apache Full (v6)    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
openssl Test:
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
Connectivity Test with ufw enabled
curl -I http://localhost/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80 after 0 ms: Connection refused
curl -I http://xx.xxx.x.x
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 02 Oct 2024 12:25:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Connection: keep-alive
telnet example.com 8080  (or 8443)
Trying xx.xxx.xx.xx...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
netstat -tlpn | grep LISTEN
tcp   0   0.0.0.0:8083       0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   2118740/nginx: mast
tcp   0   0.xx.xx.x.x:443    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   2121968/nginx: mast
tcp   0   0.xx.xx.x.x:80     0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   2121968/nginx: mast
tcp   0   0 127.0.0.1:9000   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   2121481/php-fpm: m
tcp6  0   0 :::8080          :::*        LISTEN   2122701/apache2
tcp6  0   0 :::8443          :::*        LISTEN   2122701/apache2
Configuration Tests
apachectl -t
Syntax OK
nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
Permission Check
ls -ld /run/php
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 220 Oct  2 07:27 /run/php/
Any clue?
Thanks a lot,
Sam
